# Python 3 nltk.data.load error

Tags: python, windows, nltk

I'm trying to load english.pickle for sentence tokenization.
Windows 7, Python 3.4

File followed by the path exists(tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle).

Here is the code:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle')
```

Here is the error:

```
OSError: No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python\\nltk_data\\tokenizers\\punkt\\PY3\\PY3\\english.pickle'
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `\\PY3` is doubled in your path.
The `nltk.data.load()` method adds `/PY3` to the path if it is called from python 3.

So it should work if you simply load the tokenizer with (removing `/PY3` from the string):

```
import nltk
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

NLTK does that to allow for the possibility of programs that could be run with python 2 and 3.

Comment: @infr1nger Strange... I just tested again on Windows 7, also Python 3.4 and it works fine. Do you get the exact same error message as before? If you get a different one, could you please show it?

Comment: I've wrote an answer. BTW how do you format your post here? Seems like wysiwyg editor don't work.  I wasn't able to light code with <pre> tags.

Comment: @infr1nger I updated my answer again to make it clearer what I did.
Make sure you actually remove `/PY3` from the call.
In the code you posted in the answer it is still present.